# Protractor test is not grabbing baseURL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a number of Protractor tests that were working fine until I updated Protractor (to 1.6.1) and Jasmine (to 2.1.1).  Now when I try to run my tests, the Chrome browser opens, but does not navigate to the baseURL. Below is my config file, with sensitive information replaced with xxx:

```
 exports.config = {
seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar',
chromeDriver: './node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver',
shardTestFiles: false,
specs: [
    'test/e2e/policy-add.spec.js'
],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
},

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
    args: ['--test-type']
    },

},

params: {
    login: {
    user: 'xxx@xxx.com',
    password: 'xxx'
    },
    webform: 'https://xxx'
},

baseUrl: 'https://xxx.xxx.com',
rootElement: 'body',
framework: 'jasmine',

onPrepare: function () {
    var loginHelpers = require('./test/e2e/helpers/login-helpers.js');
    loginHelpers.login();
}
```

};

This is how I am using browser.get:

```
this.navigate = function(url){
    browser.get(url);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
};
```

I am calling that function with:

```
globalHelpers.navHelpers.navigate('#/');
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `browser.get()`?

Comment: Can you call `browser.get('#/')` directly in your test and see what happens? Does it fail to navigate or does it try to navigate to '#/' without the base url? (btw, you're not using jasmine2 since you specifically specified jasmine in your config file)

Comment: Tried browser.get('#/'), and also browser.get() with the full http address.  Both had the same effect.  The browser loads but does not navigate, and "data;" is in the url field.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was with calling the login function in the onPrepare section of the config file.  When I moved the login function to the spec file, the browser opened and navigated to the base URL.